# RewriteCond breaking the RewriteRule for no apparent reason

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've just started playing with mod_rewrite and I'm trying to forward all requests to old html file to go to php files instead.

Here's the .htaccess contents:

```
RewriteCond $1.php -f
RewriteCond $1.html !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php
```

The problem is it doesn't work when I type in a url to a html page, I get a 404. Nothing in the error logs of Apache, just the 404 in the access log. It should redirect to the php.

Now, the index.php does exist and I can go to that directly and the old index.html file doesn't exist.

Yet, if I comment out the line
    RewriteCond $1.php -f
It all works fine, i.e. it forwards my index.html requests to index.php.

Any ideas why? The -f should test that the 'file exists' and $1 should be 'the file', I think?

By the way, does anyone have a good, friendly mod_rewrite tutorial they'd recommend?

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess you need not use `^` and `$`. All the rules apply to the urls relative to the current directory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow, I've already setRewriteBase /myproject/ and where am I supposed to put the ^ ? I thought ^ was just the regex to match the start of the string? Could you be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. Did you miss that the first two lines are Rewrite Conditions though and not Rewrite Rules?